# как быстро создать LESS файл в Webstorm

Tags: less, webstorm

Когда нажимаю в Webstorm File/New
то в меню появляются стандартные типы файлов, но Less среди них отсутствует

Приходится нажимать File и вручную печатать style.less
Скажите пожалуйста - можно ли как показать Less в списке стандартных расширений?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, можно использовать **New | Stylesheet | Kind: = Less File**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это недостаточно быстрый способ, и хочется просто видеть `Less` в списке **File | New**, можно создать собственный шаблон в **Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!